# What's the best way to get started flying?

Tags: general-aviation

I'm considering flying.  I'd like to find out what is the best way to start.

Comment: Find a flight school and take a discovery flight. What country are you asking about?

Comment: Consider gliding. It's much much cheaper...

Comment: I'm in Israel.  I don't know anyone who flies here so I guess I'll follow the advice above.

Comment: Your profile says New York. Consider getting flight training in the US; it will be much cheaper. Or in Europe.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll consider that.  I heard GA in the US is the best in the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>I find climbing into the aircraft a good first step ;) Sorry, couldn't resist!</sub>

---

The best way to start is to find and visit a local airfield near where you live.

Most local airfields have some level of training taking place, and if the closest to you does not then another, perhaps slightly farther afield, will do.

Visit one of these flying schools and ask to speak to an instructor, a CFI, or an examiner. They will give you more details such as the aircraft they fly, the typical syllabus and the expected costs.

From there, you might like to start with a "trial flight" - typically 30-45 minute flight where you get to take controls and get a feel for piloting an aircraft.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  It's really more of a dream of mine but I'll try to follow your advice.

Comment: @user6035379 it starts as a dream for everyone. Its up to you if you want to turn it into a reality!